# Piecewise Iterated Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

[image]

I have tried to find these integrals, I'm not sure how to deal with the if conditions, or gain some sort of geometric interpretation of the if conditions. I suspect that f does not contradict Tonelli's Theorem because f is not integrable on the unit square. Any hints as to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just calculate. We have 
\begin{align*}
  \int_0^1 f(x,y)\, dx &= \int_0^y f(x,y) \, dx + \int_y^1 f(x,y)\, dx\\
       &= \int_0^y y^{-2}\, dx + \int_y^1 -x^{-2}\, dx\\
       &= y^{-1} + \left[\frac 1x\right]_y^1\\
       &= y^{-1} + 1 - y^{-1}\\
       &= 1.
\end{align*}
Hence $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)\, dx\, dy = 1$. On the other hand
\begin{align*}
  \int_0^1 f(x,y)\, dy &= \int_0^x f(x,y) \, dy + \int_x^1 f(x,y)\, dy\\
       &= \int_0^x -x^{-2}\, dy + \int_x^1 y^{-2}\, dy\\
       &= -x^{-1} + \left[-\frac 1y\right]_x^1\\
       &= -x^{-1} - 1 + x^{-1}\\
       &= -1.
\end{align*}
Hence $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)\, dx\, dy = -1$.

Comment: I was so close to having this typed up! +1